# Matplotlib plot settings

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got pyplot/MatplotLib to plot a set of data for me, however, I use up quite few lines of code to accomplish this:

```
fig1,axes1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (12,8))
axes1.set_title(label='Stress vs Strain', fontsize=30, weight='bold', va = 'bottom')
axes1.set_xlabel(xlabel='Strain', fontsize=24, va = 'top')
axes1.set_ylabel(ylabel='Stress (Pa)', fontsize=24)
axes1.ticklabel_format(style='sci',scilimits=(0,0), axis='y')
axes1.tick_params(labelsize=24, pad=10)
axes1.xaxis.offsetText.set_fontsize(20)
axes1.yaxis.offsetText.set_fontsize(20)
```

Is there a more concise way of setting the above properties and more?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may use [`rcParams`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) to preset some (but not all) of the mentionned properties. Apart, the code looks good.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I'll combine rcparams and a function as suggested by DavidG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap all the plot formatting in a function and call it each time you want to plot something so that if you have a lot of figures you don't have to keep repeating the code. Below is a *very* simple example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def format_plot(ax, xlabel, ylabel, title):
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)

fig1, axes1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (12, 8))
format_plot(axes1, "some x label", "some y label", "a title")

plt.show()
```

You could combine this with setting some [rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#matplotlib-rcparams) for parameters that will stay constant throughout your script:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 24
```

Comment: Note that the example you used here is overly simplified, since this particular case can be easily achieved in one single line `ax.set(title="a title", xlabel="some x label", ylabel="some y label")` without any extra function.